# Use of "substitute"

Tags: grammar, objects

I know that *substitute* is often used with a prepositional phrase as in: "I can substitute this book with yours." But can I use it with a direct object alone as in the following?

"I will *substitute* you once you're gone."

Comment: The object of *substitute* is the thing being used in place of the original, so you're suggesting that the person be replaced by that same person.

Answer (score 0):

> "I will substitute you once you're gone."

You can *almost* say this, but it doesn't mean exactly the same thing: in

> "I will substitute *for* you once you're gone,"

*substitute for* doesn't mean replace (as Cathy's answer), but *stand in for*, implying the substitution is temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a baseball team.  The manager might say "I'm going to substitute Frank in right field."  This means that Frank will play the right field position in place of whoever had previously played that position.

The object of "substitute" is the thing being used as a replacement, not the thing being replaced.